# Cleanest way to return variable used in expression, without writing it twice

Tags: php, coding-style

Consider this example, the variable used in the expression is returned if expression is true, but the variable is written twice:

```
if(!is_null($arr['a-really-long']['variable'])) {
    return $arr['a-really-long']['variable'];
}
```

This is one solution but I would need an extra variable.

```
$return_array = $arr['a-really-long']['variable'];
if(!is_null($return_array)) {
    return $return_array;
}
```

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Well both examples are same (in 2nd you just use another var lol) dont you think? @1st is good.

Comment: Yes they are the same! Just curious about best coding practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
if(!is_null($temp = $arr['a-really-long']['variable'])) {
    return $temp;
}
```